# SubSonic Collection Top 1

Tags: subsonic, collections

Is there way in next piece of code to only get the first record?

```
Dal.TreeHtmlExportsCollection treeHtmlExportsCollection =
  new Dal.TreeHtmlExportsCollection().Where(Dal.TreeHtmlExports.Columns.TreeId, treeId).
  OrderByDesc(Dal.TreeHtmlExports.Columns.DateCreated).Load();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using the Query tool like so: (requires SubSonic 2.1)

```
var query = new Select()
     .Top("1")
     .From(TreeHtmlExports.Schema)
     .Where(TreeHtmlExports.Columns.TreeId).IsEqualTo(treeId)
     .OrderDesc(TreeHtmlExports.Columns.DateCreated);

treeHtmlExportCollection = query.ExecuteAsCollection<TreeHtmlExportsCollection>();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I get this error :

Error 2 Property or indexer 'SubSonic.SqlQuery.TopSpec' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only C:\Users\LIC.TELEVIC\_PROJECTS\_TELEVIC\Edumatic3\edumatic-3-framework-server-.NET\Edumatic3.Business\ReportLogic.cs 44 4 Edu3.Business

Comment: var query = new Select().Top("1").From(TreeHtmlExports.Schema).Where(TreeHtmlExports.Columns.TreeId).IsEqualTo(treeId)
    .OrderDesc(TreeHtmlExports.Columns.DateCreated);
   
   Dal.TreeHtmlExportsCollection treeHtmlExportsCollection = query.ExecuteAsCollection<TreeHtmlExportsCollection>();